# How was this question not a real question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I'm just wanting some clarity of why this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/187032/what-is-the-differences-between-sli-and-crossfire-closed) was closed.  It states that the question is "ambiguous, vague, incomplete, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form", however I feel that the question is pretty clear:

What are the differences?

Why are some motherboard supported of one type?

Is there a way to have both work?

I'm just wanting some clarity of this so that I can write better question further on.

Comment: +1 - I was wondering myself.  It sounded like @Ivo Flipse thought it was essentially pointless to ask.

Comment: Ya that's the vibe that I got.

Comment: I disagree. We did a panel peer review and didn't find the question as clear cut as what you did. I doubt you did it intentionally. Also please note, we will not always responds to question as to why something was closed. The debate that follows is often just not valuable to the community. **Please Note** I am not objecting to this particular request, but rather referring to in general. Again experience has taught us a few good lessons :)

Comment: Since @Diago already perfected answered it, I just want to add: don't take it personal, I really appreciate your input to the site. Let this question just be the exception :-) It's friday after all!

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: TGIF!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple. It's a debate and a discussion. It's trying to compare Intel to AMD. It is not a specific question. Better known as flame bait.

That question will lead to:

- Trolls, because it's going to come up in google and every person with an opinion is going to post
- Makes no technical sense, comparing apples to oranges.
- It's a discussion. This is not a forum.

Being around on the site for a while makes us very aware of what type of questions attracts what audiences, and that question was going to end up becoming a major problem.

**Be aware. The moderators close based on history and the overall good of the site. Experience has taught us how google etc. reacts to questions and the results, and therefore we have very very strict closing policies**

*(I was opting to close it as not a real question based on the second point above, however it's a very thin line)*

Comment: Oh ok, I can see how that would present a problem.  How do I ask technical questions like that, yet stray away from this issue?

Comment: @KronoS. You don't. This is not a **discussion forum**. That is not a technical question. You need to research each technology and honestly, wikipedia, as well as NVidia and ATI's webpages offer complete explanations for those. You wouldn't ask how an Intel chip works on SU would you? Same logic. SU is not about **technical questions** but rather **technical problems with X**. Make sense?